# Scala/Play: JSON serialization issue

Tags: json, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, jackson

I have a simple custom data structure which I use to map the results from the database:

```
case class Filter(id: Int, table: String, name: String, Type: String, structure: String)
```

The resulting object type is `List[Filter]` and if converted to JSON, it should look something like this:

```
[
    {
        "id":           1,
        "table":        "table1",
        "name":         "name1",
        "Type":         "type1",
        "structure":    "structure1"
    },
    {
        "id":           2,
        "table":        "table2",
        "name":         "name2",
        "Type":         "type2",
        "structure":    "structure2"
    }
]
```

Now when I try to serialize my object into JSON

```
val result: String = Json.toJson(filters)
```

I am getting something like

```
No Json deserializer found for type List[Filter]. Try to implement an implicit Writes or Format for this type.
```

How do I solve this seemingly simple problem without writing some ridiculous amount of boilerplate?

My stack is Play 2.2.1, Scala 2.10.3, Java 8 64bit

Comment: did you check if you're having problems with "Type" as the name of the field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer**:

Just add:

```
implicit val filterWrites = Json.writes[Filter]
```

**Longer answer**:

If you look at the definition of Json.toJson, you will see that its complete signature is:

```
def toJson[T](o: T)(implicit tjs: Writes[T]): JsValue = tjs.writes(o)
```

`Writes[T]` knows how to take a `T` and transform it to a `JsValue`. You will need to have an implicit `Writes[Filter]` around that knows how to serialize your `Filter` instance. The good news is that Play's JSON library comes with a macro that can instantiate those `Writes[_]` for you, so you don't have to write boring code that transforms your case class's fields into JSON values. To invoke this macro and have its value picked up by implicit search add the line above to your scope.

Comment: Doesn't seem to like it - the error says `No unapply function found`. Any idea what that is?

Comment: The following code compiles and works for me: https://gist.github.com/thesamet/7419702

Comment: FWIW, the macro tries to look for `unapply` in the *companion object* for your case class. Are you sure `Filter` refers to a *case class* and not a class or a trait?

Comment: There was a problem with scopes, but now it's working. One thing is confusing though - the line `implicit val filterWrites = Json.writes[Filter]`. This new val `filterWrites` is not really used anywhere, so why does it have to be declared?

Comment: It does get used, just implicitly. It is passed to the call to Json.toJson in the second parameter list. Instead of the `implicit val` you can just pass this value explictly:

 `Json.toJson(filters)(Json.writes[Filter])`